# Group by Foreign Key and show related items - Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have the following models:

```
class Company(CachedModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class UserExtendedProfile(CachedModel):

    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I basically need to get a list of users ordered by company like this:

```
Company A
    User 1
    User 2

Company B
    User 3 
    user 4
```

I tried a few things, and the closest I could get to is:

```
users = UserExtendedProfile.objects.values('company', 'user').order_by('company')
```

However this would just give me results something like this:

```
[{'company': 1L, 'user': 17L}, {'company': 1L, 'user': 6L}, {'company': 2L, 'user': 15L}]
```

Any inputs?

Thanks

Comment: Your example output doesn't aggregate or count.

Comment: why don't you try join and raw query

Comment: I have the SQL working the raw query way, but just wanted to know if there is a way to do it through the ORM.

Comment: ok thats sounds great, will try to find if any.

Comment: What would be the SQL to write this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can add multiple arguments on your `order_by()` method. Therefore you can do ordering inside orderings.

```
users = UserExtendedProfile.objects.values('company', 'user').order_by('company', 'user')
```

For a structure like:

```
[{ company: [user1, user2, ] }, ]
```

Try using a **defaultdict**

```
from collections import defaultdict 
users = defaultdict(list)
for result in UserExtendedProfile.objects.values('company', 'user').order_by('company', 'user'):
    users[result['company']].append(result['user'])
```

With this you should get on **users** the structure you want.

Comment: but, this is just a different way of representing the result set, I am looking for something like: `{ company: [user1, user2, ] }`

Comment: I've edited the post with the response. I don't think django has any way to do it directly from the queryset. However the response I've post should have your answer. 
Regards

Comment: Great.. I just need to figure out a way to get the objects instead of the ids, and I am all set.. Thanks :)

Comment: In 2021, is there any way to do this directly using the ORM?

Answer (score 7):

If you are simply trying to accomplish this for display purposes, take a look at: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup

It lets you do just that inside the template.