# How to get reverse relationship values as a list

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

assume i have some models like this.

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    FullName = models.CharField(max_lenth = 100)

class Projects(models.Model):
    EmployeeFK = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
    ProjectName = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

class Departments(models.Model):
    EmployeeFK = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
    DateJoined = models.DateField()
```

i want to get my output like this.

```
[ 
  {"id" : 1 , "FullName" : "John Doe 1" , "projects_ids" : [1,2,3] , "departments_ids" : [1,2,5]} ,
  {"id" : 2 , "FullName" : "John Doe 2" , "projects_ids" : [17,18,20] , "departments_ids" : [6,2,5]},
 ]
```

how can i do this efficiently regarding that there may be hundreds or thousands of employees.

Comment: I had a similar question a couple of years ago - Refer this to get a general idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12731897/group-by-foreign-key-and-show-related-items-django

Comment: @karthikr your solution is very helpful but because i need to fetch multiple reverse relationships and using a large loop i will encounter performance issues.

Comment: @SantaXYZ, I amended my answer, have a look.  I basically mocked up a bunch of dummy data and ran the queries for time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `related_name` to your foreign keys.  So `EmployeeFK = models.ForeignKey(Employee, related_name='projects')`.  Then, once you have an instance of Employee you can do `employee.projects.all()` to get all the projects that relate to that employee.  Do the same for your Departments model.

```
def make_dict(employee, projects, departments):
    result = {'id': employee.id, 'FullName': employee.FullName}
    result['projects_ids'] = [p.id for p in projects]
    result['departments_ids'] = [d.id for d in departments]
    return result

def create_structure():
    result = [make_dict(e, e.projects.all(), e.departments.all()) for e in Employee.objects.all()]
    return result
```

Perhaps that will do what you want?  I haven't used Django in a little while, so specific syntax might be slightly off.

EDIT:

As you seem to be very interested in efficiency I did a little bit of testing.  I created a dummy project/app with the models you provided, using sqlite3 on my system's SSD.  I dummied up 1000 employee entries, 10000 project entries and 5000 department entries.  I loaded all of the employees, then randomly assigned projects and departments to them. Finally, I added the two procedures I gave you above (amended to `e.projects_set.all()` and `e.departments_set.all()` since I kept your code exactly as is) and let it go.  The result was a list of 1000 dictionaries, each dictionary representing one employee.  An example, from the first entry:

```
{'departments_ids': [4279, 4789], 'FullName': u'Jedidiah Strosin', 'id': 1, 'projects_ids': [1051, 1198, 1715, 2991, 3322, 4934]}
```

I repeated the procedure five times, unloading the admin shell each time so it was fresh.  The average time needed to pull all 1000 employees, get their projects and departments, and create the dictionaries was fewer than 3 seconds for each of the five runs.  Notice that this is using sqlite, not exactly known for massive speed (though the SSD does help).

Comment: you're right but because i need to get my results in the format that i explained i need to run large loops and many queries.

Comment: Adding related_name is irrelevant: if you don't define it, you can still use the default related name which is (eg) project_set.

Comment: Right, I couldn't remember the full syntax for the relation, but `related_name` popped in my head immediately.  I do like the explicit definition, but it's not necessary.

Comment: @paidhima your solutions works but when you have 1000 employees around 4000 queries will run and it will cause performance issues even if you use select_related and evaluate querysets before they get into the loop.

Comment: @SantaXYZ In that case, you need to provide more information.  Just asking for an efficient way isn't helpful, because we don't know the context.  How often are these queries run?  How often do they need to run?  What have you already tried, and how has it affected performance in production?

Comment: @paidhima i will cache result dictionary for a long time and serve it to user from cache. i didn't try any solutions yet but i thought to loading all related tables to memory and then doing assignments (but it may cause memory issues) and because of this i asked for a solution with less database queries and memory efficiency.

Comment: Ok, that helps.  You could certainly just load the tables into memory and work through it that way, but I am still of the opinion that letting the database server do what database servers are good at (lots of queries, really fast) is the best course of action.  The answer, though, depends on what's best in your environment.  Try it a few different ways and see which works best for you.

Comment: @paidhima your answer was really helpful and accepeted. thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
class College(CommonFields):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    fees = models.IntegerField()

class Department(CommonFields):
    strength = models.IntegerField(default=60)
    college = models.ForeignKey(College, on_delete= models.CASCADE, related_name= "dept")

college.dept.all()

def make_dict(college, department):
    result = {'College Name': college.name}
    result['dept_id'] = [d.id for d in dept]
    result['dept_name'] = [d.name for d in dept]
    return result

def create_structure():
    result = [make_dict(e, e.dept.all()) for e in College.objects.all()]
    return result

I am getting an error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 41, in <module>
NameError: name 'college' is not defined
```

Comment: It would be a better answer if you add some explanation to it