# Convert a django queryset to json tree

Tags: json, ajax, django, python-3.x, django-queryset

Assume I have two tables in my model:

```
class Country(models.Model):
      CountryName = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class City(models.Model):
      CityName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
      Country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
```

And in my view I make a json:

```
list = City.objects.annotate(CountryName=F('Country__CountryName')).values('CityName', 'CountryName').prefetch_related('Country')
return HttpResponse(json.dumps([any_entry for any_entry in list]))
```

In result I receive something like:

```
{[{CityName: 'Vancouver', CountryName: 'Canada'},
  {CityName: 'Montreal', CountryName: 'Canada'},
  {CityName: 'Dallas', CountryName: 'USA'}]}
```

While I want something like:

```
{[
  {
    CountryName: 'Canada', 
    Cities: [{CityName: 'Vancouver'},
             {CityName: 'Montreal'}]
  },
  {
    CountryName: 'USA',
    Cities: [{CityName: 'Dallas'}]
  }
]}
```

Or at least:

```
{
 Canada: ['vancouver','Montreal'],
 USA: ['Dallas']
}
```

Comment: Check here and see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12731897/group-by-foreign-key-and-show-related-items-django

Comment: @souldeux: Thanks but what if I had 3 levels instead of 2. (Consider adding states) And are you sure this method has the best performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I used the following code:

```
from collections import defaultdict 
city_list = defaultdict(list)

for any_city in City.objects.annotate(CountryName=F('Country__CountryName')).values('CityName', 'CountryName'):
    city_list[any_city['CountryName']].append(any_city['CityName'])
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(city_list))
```