# Groupby using Django's ORM to get a dictionary of lists from the queryset of model with foreignkey

Tags: python, django, postgresql, group-by, django-orm

I have two models, `Business` and `Employee`:

```py
from django.db import models

class Business(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    # ...


class Employee(models.Model):
    business = models.ForeignKey(
        Business,
        related_name="employees",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    # ...
```

Here's a sample data:

```py
Business.objects.create(name="first company")
Business.objects.create(name="second company")

Employee.objects.create(business_id=1, name="Karol")
Employee.objects.create(business_id=1, name="Kathrine")
Employee.objects.create(business_id=1, name="Justin")
Employee.objects.create(business_id=2, name="Valeria")
Employee.objects.create(business_id=2, name="Krista")
```

And I want to get a dictionary of lists, keys being the businesses and values being the list of employees. I can do so using [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) on the Business model. A query like this:

```py
businesses = Business.objects.prefetch_related("employees")

for b in businesses:
    print(b.name, '->', list(b.employees.values_list("name", flat=True)))
```

Which gives me this:

```py
first company -> ['Karol', 'Kathrine', 'Justin']
second company -> ['Valeria', 'Krista']
```

And this is exactly what I want and I can construct my dictionary of lists. But the problem is that I only have access to the `Employee` model. Basically I only have a QuerySet of all Employees and I want to achieve the same result. I figured I could use [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related), because I do need the business objects, but this query:

```py
Employee.objects.select_related("business")
```

Gives me this QuerySet:

```py
<QuerySet [<Employee: Employee object (1)>, <Employee: Employee object (2)>, <Employee: Employee object (3)>, <Employee: Employee object (4)>, <Employee: Employee object (5)>]>
```

And I don't know how to group by business using Django's ORM from this QuerySet. How can I do that?

Here's how I'm doing it so far:

```py
employees = {}
    for employee in Employee.objects.only("business"):
        employees.setdefault(employee.business, []).append(employee.id)
```

I do this because I need the business objects to perform some operation on the list of their employees. And this works. But I want to do the same without the for loop and in a single query. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ArrayAgg](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#arrayagg) annotation for this purpose. Try this:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import ArrayAgg

Employee.objects.annotate(business_names=ArrayAgg('business__name'))
```

**Edit**:

I initially thought you want this side of relationship. I re-read and to achieve this from the other (business) side, you shouldn't filter Employees grouped by business but instead you filter Businesses and annotate employees that are related to that business.

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import ArrayAgg

Business.objects.annotate(employee_names=ArrayAgg('employees__name'))
```

This is more straightforward as grouping would look something like this (note clearing order_by so it doesn't break grouping issued by values):

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import ArrayAgg

Employee.objects.order_by().values('business__name').annotate(employee_names=ArrayAgg('name'))
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this solves the problem. All I get is a list, with one business in it, for every employee. But I want to get the list of employees for every business.

Comment: check the edit I made

Comment: This is really close to what I want. It gives me a list of dictionaries with businesses and their employees. But it gives the business ids as values and I need the businesses' objects. Do you know how I can achieve that?

Comment: If you need objects you need to do the grouping yourself like Sarthak Khandelwal suggested. I assumed you only need the data, which works well for more functional than OOP code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to group, you can use a order by and then try grouping them over a simple loop. Something like:

```
query_set = Employee.objects.values('name', 'business').order_by('business')
```

For changing the structure a simple loop like this would work

```
from collections import defaultdict 
employees = defaultdict(list)
for result in Employee.objects.values('name', 'business').order_by('business'):
    users[result['business']].append(result['name'])
```

A similar example is giving [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12731897/group-by-foreign-key-and-show-related-items-django) involving two foregin keys

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did see that example. But I want to see if it's possible to the same with one query using Django's ORM. I edited my question to reflect on that.